# Using COM assemblies in Java

Tags: java, com

I want to be able to use a COM assembly in a Java program. From what I have read Java is capable of communicating with a COM assembly. However the ways of doing this involved the Visual J++ Type Library Wizard to convert the dll into a jar. Obviously J++ is no longer in existence and I doubt the Type Library Wizard is either.

Is there any way to perform the conversion from a COM assembly to a file usable by a Java IDE?

(I know you can talk to .NET languages using the JNI or commercial applications such as JNBridge. This seems like it would be simpler if possible though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very best open source free one J-interop. Sorry for sounding like a moving advertisement, but I used this one in couple of years and my experience was quite good. This is a complete implementation of the DCOM protocol. Which means that you can connect straight from a linux PC to your COM server on windows without any JNI.

http://j-interop.dimentrix.com

Of course the alternatives are JNI wrapper. J-Interga can be an option , but it is payed. Probably some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use JNBridgePro to do this.  First, create a Runtime-Callable Wrapper (RCW) for your COM assembly, then proxy the RCW like any other .NET assembly and call it from .NET using JNBridgePro.

Disclosure: I'm with JNBridge.